# Xcode 11 debugger crashes on breakpoint, can't find Foundation.h

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode11

My macOS app compiles and runs fine, but since switching to Xcode 11, I can no longer debug from breakpoints. The debugger always crashes with a bunch of messages like this:

```
warning: Swift error in scratch context: /foobar/Foo-Bridging-Header.h:14:9: note: in file included from /foobar/Foo-Bridging-Header.h:14:
#import "TPPreciseTimer.h"
    ^

error: /foobar/Timer/TPPreciseTimer.h:9:9: error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    ^

/foobar/Timer/TPPreciseTimer.h:9:9: note: did not find header 'Foundation.h' in framework 'Foundation' (loaded from '/System/Library/Frameworks')
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    ^

error: failed to import bridging header '/foobar/Foo-Bridging-Header.h'
.
Shared Swift state for Foo has developed fatal errors and is being discarded.
REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.

Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.
```

Anyone know a workaround for something like this?

My coworkers still on Xcode 10.3 are not having this issue with the same codebase.

Comment: It's not happening anymore. Maybe Apple fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Removing `/Users/{user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` directory helped.